# How do I stop Database deploy from removing Server Triggers?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, triggers, database-project

I am deploying my database using a `Visual-Studio` database project and the `Publish` wizzard.

The initial deploy works fine and my database is the same as my project. I then apply a third party tool to my database which adds triggers to all my tables.

I then deploy an update to my database and it removes the third party triggers from my database.

how do I stop my deploy from removing triggers that are on the server but not in the project?

I have tried unticking "Drop DML triggers not in source" in the `Advance Deployment Settings` but this has not worked.

[image]

Anyone else have any ideas?

**PS:**
I am using `Visual studio 2015`

The rest of my deployment settings are as follows:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the second deploy recreate the tables?

Comment: Also, I see a checkbox in the picture called "Do not drop database triggers", have you tried checking that?

Comment: @DavidG I will double check now if it re-creates tables. For some reason I cannot check any of those properties in the grey table

Comment: Or perhaps you have "always re-create database" checked?

Comment: @DavidG I have checked deployment options and don't have `always re-create database` checked. The tables aren't being re-creeate in between deploys. I will add screenshots of all my deployment settings

Comment: @DavidG I found the problem. `Deployment options` in the project properties did not tally up with the `Publish` dialog `Deployment Options`. Could be a bug in 2015? Could be me being stupid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the problem.

When I was setting my `Advanced Deployment Properties` I was doing it by:

1. Right Clicking Database - Properties
2. Going to debug tab (there is no Deploy tab in 2015 like the documentation mentions)
3. Changing my Deployment Options here using "Advanced" button at the bottom.

I then realised that when I clicked `Publish` on my project there was an `Advanced` button on here.

Clicking the `Advanced` button on the `Publish` dialog showed different options to what I was getting on the projects properties.

I removed the `Drop DML Triggers` check from this screen and it worked

In addition to this. I then clicked `Save Profile` and added it to my project using `Add Existing Item` I then used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114152/2987066) to set this profile as my default publishing profile